# Как сделать что бы бот проигрывал музыку через spotify

Tags: python, discord.py

Делал бота который будет проигрывать музыку через ютюб, но узнал что библиотеку **youtube_dl** заблокировали, и хотел бы узнать как можно изменить код что бы бот проигрывал музыку через spotify, или другую музыкальную платформу.

Код:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "worstaudio/best", "noplaylist": "False", "simulate": "True", "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio"}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options": "-vn"}


PREFIX = "."
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents)





#-------------------------------------------------PLAY-----------------------------------------------------------------#
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx,url):
    vc = await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()

    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        if "https://" in url:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=True)
        else:
            info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{url}", download=True)["entries"][0]

        link = info["formats"][0]["url"]
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegAudio(executable="ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe", source=link, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))


print('ready')
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос) Тоже хотел это спросить